# Hosting fonts on Azure CDN for a Wordpress site on Ubuntu 14.0.4? CORS issues

Tags: wordpress, apache, cors, azure-storage, w3-total-cache

I have an Azure storage account, with CDN setup to have 5 subdomains pointing to the storage account (cdn1.domain.com, cdn2.domain.com, -- cdn5.domain.com).

I use the W3 Total Cache plugin for performance, particularly to host static files on the Azure CDN. The plugin uploads all the files fine and the site can access images, css, scripts, etc... no problem. However, fonts don't load.

**Gets the following error:**

> Font from origin 'http://cdn1.domain.com' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://domain.com' is therefore not allowed access.

The wordpress site is hosted on DigitalOcean, using Apache on Ubuntu 14.0.4. I added the following to the apache2.conf:

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

That did not work. After some research it looks like Azure doesn't allow CORS by default, so I created a little C# app to **change CORS rules on my storage account**, like so:

```
var storageAccount =
    new CloudStorageAccount(
        new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials("accountname", "accountkey"), true);
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var blobServiceProperties = new ServiceProperties
{
    HourMetrics = null,
    MinuteMetrics = null,
    Logging = null,
};
blobServiceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(new CorsRule
{
    AllowedHeaders = new List<string> { "*" },
    AllowedMethods = CorsHttpMethods.Get,
    AllowedOrigins = new List<string> { "*" },
    ExposedHeaders = new List<string> { "*" },
    MaxAgeInSeconds = 3600 // 30 minutes 
});

blobClient.SetServiceProperties(blobServiceProperties);
```

This should basically open up the storage to all origins... but still get the same error. So I figured maybe it was caching of some kind. So I re-uploaded all the files to the same container, then waited about 6 hours.

The error still persists. I feel like I've tried all one should have to in order to get fonts loading from an Azure CDN.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

CORS for most CDN’s just works by default for case where wildcard is set for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. The wildcard case works as the CDN will cache the response for the first request it gets. For cases where customer needs to allow specific origins additional configuration typically needs to be set on a CDN to enable this. From the Azure CDN capabilities available via the Azure Management Portal today you need to enable query string setting for the CDN endpoint  and then using a unique query string for requests from each allowed domain. The enable query string setting will result in the CDN caching a separate object for every unique query string. For very large customers of the Azure CDN there is a supplemental portal that has more sophisticated capabilities – but it is currently only available to a restricted number of customers.